# Overriding The Notepad++ File Size Limit

Tags: notepad++, file-management, text-editing, memory-limit, size

I had a text file I was working with in Notepad++, which I accidentally closed and now I can't open it again because it says "File is too big to be opened by Notepad++".

I was editing it just fine a few moments ago, until I closed it by mistake with the keyboard shortcut Ctrl + W. When I tried to reopen it (Ctrl + Shift + T), it wouldn't open with that error. My first reaction is that I have just gone a bit past the file size limit. I've tried to open it various ways from dragging + dropping, open dialog, etc...

This is a file that I typed (and copied) all myself over the past few years, and it's not massive <9Mb. I have been able to edit it just fine because it was open already, and never encountered any issues even with Notepad++ being restarted during power outages, system reboots, etc... It always opened up my files including this one.

I have been saving different versions but never closed it before this.

And now due to one silly keystroke by mistake, I lost my ability to edit it - permanently it would seem?

Is there any way to temporarily override this limit, to make it just a tiny bit larger for the moment?

Yes I'm aware there are other editors I could use. I'd prefer not to have to use another editor as Notepad++ is what I've been using for basically everything and am most familiar with. It's what I'm using for every other text file. This file is growing pretty slowly, and I don't mind a small amount of performance degradation. I haven't encountered any other issues thus far. As I said, I've been editing this same file at a similar size (within 1Mb) for months until today I closed it.

I also want to understand where this limit comes from and whether it's a fixed value or based on something in the system. Much smaller files are opening fine, but other slightly smaller files are also failing, including some which I am pretty sure I opened in the past.

I have also tried disabling the "Clickable Links Settings" and that didn't make any difference.

Any help or ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I've opened files multiple GB in size with n++. can you open it in just notepad?

Comment: check [Notepad++'s backup folder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29617349/995714)

Answer (score 1):

9 MB is **not** the maximum size that Notepad++ (NPP) can open, at least for 64-bit v. 8.5.8 running on Windows 10, v. 22H. As an experiment, A 33 MB PDF file and a 77 MB executable were each opened in Notepad++ in less than one second (displaying gibberish, of course, in the text editor).

The error message, "File is too big to be opened by Notepad++," is bogus. Some other issue is preventing the file from being opened. Here are a few things to try:

- Copy the file **twice**, to *two* different folders.

  - One copy will serve as a backup.
  - The other copy can be used in experiments to fix any issue with it.
- In Windows Explorer, check the size of the original and the two copies. Are all three close to 9 MB? If not, there might have been an error when saving the file.
- Try opening the copy for experiments with NPP.
- If that fails, try opening it in a hex editor (a file editor that does not attempt to interpret text, but just displays each byte). [HxD Hex Editor](https://mh-nexus.de/en/) is one good, free, hex editor, and there are [many alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/hxd/). Some hex editors can open files of many gigabytes (I just opened a 4 GB Windows 10 ISO in HxD!). Skip to the end and look for strange characters that might be causing the issue. For example, some editors don't like a series of [null characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) (\0 in ASCII). If the file contains nulls, edit them to another value, e.g., [space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character).
- It is also possible the NPP executable is damaged. [Download](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) the latest version and install it, **without** installing the additional plugins, at first (since it could be a plugin is causing the issue). If that opens the file, then install plugins and see if that causes a problem.